# Session Lifetime in Laravel

Tags: laravel, session

Try to set session lifetime in .env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file

SESSION_LIFETIME=1

SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true

SESSION_HTTP_ONLY=true
```

When i access webpage and do some process more than 1 minute  the session is not cut. But when i idle and not connect or do some process connect to controller it will cut the session?

Because some thread said the session should read the time the session is first created so even there's activities the session should be reset after 1 minutes

Comment: It's in seconds not minutes.

Comment: *"When i access webpage and do some process"* - isn't the lifetime keep being refreshed between requests?

Comment: @EHFShahab "_Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session to be allowed to remain idle before it expires._" from `/config/session.php` says it's minutes